# elastic search Nested query filter based on date is not returning correct results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have nested query where in i am filtering the present days data and later aggregating the data using date-histogram aggregation with hourly interval, but in date-histogram output it is returning the previous day's data also. is filter is not working?

Here is my Query:

```
POST finalalertbrowser/_search?size=0
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "match_phrase": {
                    "projectId.keyword": "******************************88"
                }
            }],
            "filter": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "errors",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "filter": 
                            {
                              "range": {
                                    "errors.time": {
                                        "gte": "now/d",
                                        "lte": "now"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "errorData": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "errors"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "errorMsg": {
                    "filter": {
                      "term": {
                            "errors.errMsg.keyword": "Uncaught TypeError: $.snapUpdate is not a function"
                        }

                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "hourlyData": {
                            "date_histogram": {
                                "field": "errors.time",
                                "interval": "hour",
                                "time_zone": "+05:30"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the output of the query is:

```
"aggregations": {
    "errorData": {
      "doc_count": 89644,
      "errorMsg": {
        "doc_count": 1861,
        "hourlyData": {
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-13T11:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520919000000,
              "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-13T12:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520922600000,
              "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-13T13:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520926200000,
              "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-13T14:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520929800000,
              "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-13T15:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520933400000,
              "doc_count": 4
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-13T16:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520937000000,
              "doc_count": 8
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-13T17:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520940600000,
              "doc_count": 6
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-13T18:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520944200000,
              "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-13T19:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520947800000,
              "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-13T20:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520951400000,
              "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-13T21:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520955000000,
              "doc_count": 4
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-13T22:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520958600000,
              "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-13T23:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520962200000,
              "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-14T00:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520965800000,
              "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-14T01:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520969400000,
              "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-14T02:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520973000000,
              "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-14T03:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520976600000,
              "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-14T04:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520980200000,
              "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-14T05:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1520983800000,
              "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-14T11:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1521005400000,
              "doc_count": 349
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-14T12:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1521009000000,
              "doc_count": 300
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-14T13:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1521012600000,
              "doc_count": 258
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-14T14:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1521016200000,
              "doc_count": 247
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-14T15:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1521019800000,
              "doc_count": 144
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-14T16:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1521023400000,
              "doc_count": 63
            },
            {
              "key_as_string": "2018-03-14T17:00:00.000+05:30",
              "key": 1521027000000,
              "doc_count": 30
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

i have executed the query on 14th march 2018 , but query is giving output from 13 March 2018.

Below is the mapping command :

```
PUT myIndexName
{
 "mappings": {
"webbrowsererror": {
     "properties": {
       "errors": {
         "type": "nested" ,
         "properties": {
           "time":{"type":"date"}
           }
       }
     }
   }
}
}
```

**and below are the sample records in the index:**

```
_source": {
          "projectId": "******************",
          "sId": "bt82x3g8v1505001600027",
          "pId": "bt82x3g8v1505001600027.1",
          "pageURL": "***************************",
          "startTime": 1505001600027,
          "country": "unknown",
          "size": 2,
          "errors": [
            {
              "sid": "bt82x3g8v1505001600027",
              "pid": "bt82x3g8v1505001600027.1",
              "browser": "Googlebot",
              "time": 1505001600028,
              "errMsg": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /",
              "url": "********************************",
              "lineNo": 161,
              "colNo": 54
            },
            {
              "sid": "bt82x3g8v1505001600027",
              "pid": "bt82x3g8v1505001600027.1",
              "browser": "Googlebot",
              "time": 1505001600058,
              "errMsg": "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #!",
              "url": "************************************************************",
              "lineNo": 3,
              "colNo": 69
            }
          ]
        }




 "_source": {
          "projectId": "shaan-shaanstack-1-1517388493060",
          "sId": "bt82x3g8v1502496000027",
          "pId": "bt82x3g8v1502496000027.1",
          "startTime": 1502496000027,
          "country": "US",
          "size": 1,
          "errors": [
            {
              "sid": "bt82x3g8v1502496000027",
              "pid": "bt82x3g8v1502496000027.1",
              "browser": "Chrome Mobile",
              "time": 1502496000128,
              "errMsg": "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #!",
              "url": "**************************************************",
              "lineNo": 2,
              "colNo": 69
            }
          ]
        }





"_source": {
          "projectId": null,
          "sId": "888888888888888",
          "pId": "bt82x3g8v1505001600027.1",
          "pageURL": "******************",
          "startTime": 1505001600027,
          "country": "unknown",
          "size": 2,
          "errors": [
            {
              "sid": "bt82x3g8v1505001600027",
              "pid": "bt82x3g8v1505001600027.1",
              "browser": "Googlebot",
              "time": 1505001600028,
              "errMsg": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /",
              "url": "***********************************",
              "lineNo": 170,
              "colNo": 54
            },
            {
              "sid": "bt82x3g8v1505001600027",
              "pid": "bt82x3g8v1505001600027.1",
              "browser": "Googlebot",
              "time": 1505001600082,
              "errMsg": "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #!",
              "url": "***********************************",
              "lineNo": 3,
              "colNo": 69
            }
          ]
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think of nested fields as part of the parent record.  Let's take the following example, I insert a single record that has 2 nested properties, one with a time of "2018-01-01T00:00:00Z" and one with a time of "2018-01-02T00:00:00Z"

Insert command:

```
POST jaytest/webbrowsererror
{
  "projectId": "******************",
  "sId": "bt82x3g8v1505001600027",
  "pId": "bt82x3g8v1505001600027.1",
  "pageURL": "***************************",
  "startTime": 1505001600027,
  "country": "unknown",
  "size": 2,
  "errors": [
    {
      "sid": "bt82x3g8v1505001600027",
      "pid": "bt82x3g8v1505001600027.1",
      "browser": "Googlebot",
      "time": "2018-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "errMsg": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /",
      "url": "********************************",
      "lineNo": 161,
      "colNo": 54
    },
    {
      "sid": "bt82x3g8v1505001600027",
      "pid": "bt82x3g8v1505001600027.1",
      "browser": "Googlebot",
      "time": "2018-01-02T00:00:00Z",
      "errMsg": "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #!",
      "url": "************************************************************",
      "lineNo": 3,
      "colNo": 69
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I can query on that and say "only return me records where errors.time is >= "2018-01-02T00:00:00Z"

```
GET jaytest/webbrowsererror/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "errors",
            "query": {
              "range": {
                "errors.time": {
                  "gte": "2018-01-02T00:00:00Z"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When you run that query you'll notice that it returns the single parent record that I inserted, but with both of the nested "errors".  That's because you're querying on the parent record.

To slice the data how you want I think the correct way would be to get rid of the nested "errors" field, and instead index each error as it's own document (instead of a nested child of a parent document).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. if i index each error as own document i may have to insert other fields which will become redundant .  Do you mean if insert data as a nested document, it will be difficult to filter out?

Comment: Having everything in separate docs that include rendundant fields is exactly what you want when storing data in a noSQL database. It's a whole different mindset from a relational database.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are a couple issues with your query:

1. for projectID you want to use a `terms` query to get an exact match
2. your `nested` query should be within the `bool/must` clause

Give this a try (note: I excluded the aggregation part):

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "errors.time": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "projectId.keyword": {
              "value": "******************************88"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "errors",
            "query": {
              "range": {
                "errors.time": {
                  "gte": "now/d",
                  "lte": "now"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Once you verify that your query is returning you only the correct data, then you can add back in your aggregation

Comment: Thank you jhiliden, If you see my query the nested query to filter present day's data is inside bool query only, and even "match_phrase" picks the documents that match all the keywords of search term..

Comment: Can you update the description to include your mapping and a couple of sample records please

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have updated my question , where i have mentioned the mapping and couple of sample  records

Comment: I added a new answer, I think I understand the problem you're seeing now.